# How to avoid weird umlaute error when using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, text-mining, sparse-matrix

I need to operate sums on a sparse dataframe considering the IDs

```
require(data.table)
sentEx = structure(list(abend = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 2), aber = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 
0), über = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0), überall = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), überlegt = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0019", 
"0021"), class = "factor"), abgeandert = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), abgebildet = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 0), abgelegt = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 3)), .Names = c("abend", 
"aber", "über", "überall", "überlegt", "ID", "abgeandert", "abgebildet", 
"abgelegt"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 16L, 17L, 18L), class = "data.frame")

sentEx  # How it looks
   abend aber über überall überlegt   ID abgeandert abgebildet abgelegt
1      1    0    1       0        0 0019          1          0        0
2      1    1    0       0        0 0019          1          0        0
16     0    0    0       0        0 0021          1          1        0
17     0    0    0       0        0 0021          0          1        0
18     2    0    0       0        0 0021          0          0        3
```

Without "umlaute" it works fine:

```
sentEx.dt <- data.table(sentEx[,-c(3,4,5)])[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=ID]
(sentExSum <- as.data.frame(sentEx.dt))  # Need again as dataframe, which looks like:
    ID abend aber abgeandert abgebildet abgelegt
1 0019     2    1          2          0        0
2 0021     2    0          1          2        3
```

But otherwise i get this error:

```
sentEx.dt <- data.table(sentEx)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=ID]
# Error in gsum(`Ã¼ber`) : object 'Ã¼ber' not found
      sentExSum <- as.data.frame(sentEx.dt)
```

Some Additional seesion info (since the issue seems to be system related - see comments):

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.1     Rcpp_0.11.0    reshape2_1.2.2 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.2
```

Also requested commands:

```
require(data.table); test.data.table()
Running C:/Users/Krohana/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/data.table/tests/tests.Rraw 
Loading required package: reshape
Loading required package: hexbin
Loading required package: xts
Loading required package: bit64
Test 167.2 not run. If required call library(hexbin) first.
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type ITime. Defaulting to continuous
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type ITime. Defaulting to continuous
Tests 487 and 488 not run. If required call library(reshape) first.
Test 841 not run. If required call library(xts) first.
Tests 897-899 not run. If required call library(bit64) first.
All 1220 tests in inst/tests/tests.Rraw completed ok in 24.321sec on Sun Mar 02 17:57:26 2014 ts/tests.Rraw completed ok in 24.638sec on Sun Mar 02 17:55:45 2014
```

Requested commands2:

```
> Encoding(names(sentEx))
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
> options(datatable.verbose=TRUE)
> options(datatable.verbose=TRUE); options(datatable.optimize=1L);
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with data.table 1.8.10 on my mac.

Comment: I've just updated to 1.9.2 and I can still not reproduce the error. Please add the output of `dput(sentEx)` to your question.

Comment: @Roland Hello, thank you! I changed the name of the end-result to `sentExSum` and now it should be reproducible. Before the `sentEx` input for the second step was overwritten, and so the error didn't occurred anymore.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Hello, thank you. It is not possible to change the caracters because the uniqueness of the words would not be preserved anymore. Another problem would be to reconstruct them back. because i may need the exact entries. Do you know another method?

Comment: Again, I cannot reproduce this error. Please provide `sentEx` in a reproducible way (using `dput`).

Comment: @Roland I added the `dput(sentEx)`.

Comment: Please add your `sessionInfo()`. I still get no error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either, even after setting LOCALE.

Comment: @Thomas Hello , Thank you for help. Yes, you'r right. I tried on another system and did not get the error. Do you have any suggestion? The other system has a convetional (not SSD) harddrive so I would prefer to work with the big data (20000 columns x 3000 rows) on this.

Comment: @Roland Hello , Thank you for help. I tried to reproduce the problem on another system and didn't get the error! Do you have any suggestion? The other system has a convetional (not SSD) harddrive so I would prefer to work with the big data (20000 columns x 3000 rows) on this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see data.table in your session info.

Comment: @Roland Added the whole output again. It is now a session from beginning to the end. Thank you for your efforts. They are really needed.

Comment: You're going to have to try to narrow down the differences between the two systems.  Have you identified *all* differences between the `sessionInfo()` output on the two systems?  Can you also report on precise versions of the operating systems (which might not be included in `sessionInfo()`, and might affect system libraries which are handling non-English characters)?

Comment: Work for me on Slovenian locale (`Slovenian_Slovenia.1250`), latest data.table and Windows 7.

Comment: @Arun Thank you! I added the required commands. They don't work properly but i can't interpret the tests. Can you please take a look?

Comment: I suggest you take this to the R public chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public until the problem is diagnosed.

Comment: @Arun THANK YOU! It works! I added the suggested code above. Please explain me briefly what the problem was, and why it now works? What `options(datatable.verbose=TRUE); options(datatable.optimize=1L)` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce either. But, there was another "object not found error" that Arun found, that I'm hoping is this one too.

Now in v1.9.3, commit 1212. From NEWS :

> o  An error "object [name] not found" could occur in some
>   circumstances, particularly after a previous error. Reported with
>   non-ASCII characters in a column name, a red herring we hope since
>   non-ASCII characters are supported in column names in data.table. Fix
>   implemented and tests added.

If it happens again, please let us know. Your test has been added verbatim to the test suite, thanks.

Comment: Thank you much. It seems that it is because of my Windows.

Comment: @alex Why do you think it's because of Windows? Are you saying you've tried v1.9.3 with this fix and it still doesn't work?